# Adding a resize listener to LayoutContainer

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using Ext-GWT 2.0.1 and GWT 1.6.4

I have a LayoutContainer that uses a RowLayout.  The widgets are added to this container with RowData(1,-1), so that when they change in height, the container also changes height accordingly.  I want to do something when this LayoutContainer changes size.  How can I add a listener that does this?  So far I have tried:

```
layoutContainer.addListener(Events.Resize, new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {
    public void handleEvent(final ComponentEvent event) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

But handleEvent never gets called.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's quite old post, but I thought answering may help someone who has just met this problem. So what is wrong in the snippet is the listener type (`ComponentEvent`). Try with `BoxComponentEvent`, because `LayoutContainer` inherits this event from its `BoxComponent` ancestor.
(http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/extjs/gxt/2.0.1/gxt-2.0.1-javadoc.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/LayoutContainer.html)

code:

```
layoutContainer.addListener(Events.Resize, new Listener<BoxComponentEvent>(){...}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this :

```
            addHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
        public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {

                       // whatever! 

        }
    }, ResizeEvent.getType());
```